# rotate (reopen) file in python3, when signal is received

Tags: python-3.x, logging, signals, logrotate

I have simple script, that logs to a logfile. This is the core of my script:

```
with open('/var/log/mail/mail.log', 'a', buffering=1) as f:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        f.write(line)
```

The file being written `/var/log/mail/mail.log` has to be rotated regularly by `logrotate`. At the moment, when `logrotate` rotates the file, my script does not realize it, and continues writing to the old (now renamed) file.

`logrotate` has the possibility to execute command after the file has been rotated. Normally, when `rsyslog` is logging, the command would be:

```
postrotate
    invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
endscript
```

But in my case, I need to send some signal to my script, and handle the signal in my script.

Also, I don't know in advance the `PID` my script is running as.

How can I best implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution for this you can watch if the inode of the open log file is the same as the path. If not reopen the file. This only works on Unix.

```
import os, sys, stat

logfile = '/var/log/mail/mail.log'

while True:
    with open(logfile, 'a', buffering=1) as f:
        f_ino = os.stat(logfile)[stat.ST_INO]
        f_dev = os.stat(logfile)[stat.ST_DEV]
        for line in sys.stdin:
            f.write(line)
            try:
                if os.stat(logfile)[stat.ST_INO] != f_ino or 
                   os.stat(logfile)[stat.ST_DEV] != f_dev:
                     break
            except OSError: # Was IOError with python < 3.4
                pass
```

Closing the file is not required as it’s handled by the `with` context manager.

The `try..except` [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) block is used to catch any error by the system function `os.stat`. It can be that during the change of the file the function returns an `OSError` (For example a `FileNotFoundError`). In this case it will pass the exception and retry the check if the inode is changed. If we omit this `try..except` block you might end up with a program that terminates.